# Convert script Jquery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert following jquery script into javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('select.ddlVarianti').on('change', function() {
        var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var tagliaSelected   = optionSelected.text();
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({
          'event':'GAevent',
          'eventID':'13',
          'eventCategory':'product',
          'eventAction':'taglia',
          'eventLabel': tagliaSelected,
        });

      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is what i did

```
  document.querySelector('select.ddlVarianti').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var optionSelected = document.querySelector(this).querySelector("option:selected");
    var tagliaSelected   = optionSelected.text();
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
      'event':'GAevent',
      'eventID':'13',
      'eventCategory':'product',
      'eventAction':'taglia',
      'eventLabel': tagliaSelected,
    });

  });
```

but i have following error..

*Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLSelectElement]' is not a valid selector.*

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Please show the HTML related to this. In particular, is there **one** `select.ddlVarianti` element, or more than one?

Comment: `document.querySelector(this)` is the code causing the problem. You can't pass an element object into `querySelector`.

Comment: For starters change this `'change', function()` to this `'change', function({ target })`. Then change this `document.querySelector(this).querySelector("option:selected");` to this `target.querySelector("option:checked");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues I can see (maybe only two):

1. `document.querySelector(this)` is passing an element object into `querySelector`. You can't do that, it accepts strings defining CSS selectors. To look within the element `this` refers to, use `this.querySelector("selector string")`. But if you want to get the seelcted option from an `HTMLSelectElement`, you can use its [`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) array instead.
2. `option:selected` is jQuery-specific. To find the first selected `option` within the `select`, you can use `"option:checked"` instead. But see #1, you don't need to do it that way.
3. The jQuery code is waiting for the `window` `load` event and then, redundantly, waiting until the DOM is ready (which it will be; `load` doesn't fire until long after it is). Your code isn't doing anything to wait for things to be ready. These days, if you're using `type="module"`, there's no need to, so that may be fine. If not, you might consider it (modules are useful), or use [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) on the script element.

You haven't said whether there is just one element or multiple but if we assume multiple, loop through the result of `querySelectorAll` to set up the handlers:

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("select.ddlVarianti")) {
    element.addEventListener("change", function () {
        const optionSelected = this.selectedOptions[0];
        if (optionSelected) {
            const tagliaSelected = optionSelected.text;
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            dataLayer.push({
                event: "GAevent",
                eventID: "13",
                eventCategory: "product",
                eventAction: "taglia",
                eventLabel: tagliaSelected,
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Live Example:

```js
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("select.ddlVarianti")) {
    element.addEventListener("change", function () {
        const optionSelected = this.selectedOptions[0];
        if (optionSelected) {
            const tagliaSelected = optionSelected.text;
            console.log(`tagliaSelected = ${tagliaSelected}`);
            /*
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            dataLayer.push({
                event: "GAevent",
                eventID: "13",
                eventCategory: "product",
                eventAction: "taglia",
                eventLabel: tagliaSelected,
            });
            */
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select class="ddlVarianti">
        <option value="A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C">Option C</option>
        <option value="D">Option D</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="ddlVarianti">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```